# How to partially unwrap a link in slate.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slate.js

Here is an example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/slate-2-images-and-links-forked-6v5hgy?file=/src/editor/link-button.tsx

I want to select the text "unlinkThis", click the unlink button, and unwraps the link partially. However, it just unwraps the entire link. Do I need to use `Transform.wrapNodes` again after `Transforms.unwrapNodes`?

Unlink button:

```
export const UnLinkButton = () => {
  const editor = useSlate();
  const isActive = isElementActive(editor);
  return (
    <button
      color={isActive ? "red" : undefined}
      onClick={async () => {
        if (isActive) {
          Transforms.unwrapNodes(editor, {
            split: true,
            match: (n) =>
              !Editor.isEditor(n) && Element.isElement(n) && n.type === "link"
          });
        }
      }}
    >
      unlink
    </button>
  );
};
```

Comment: like you want to move "unlinkThis" - word under cursor - from a link, but keeping all the `https://....` still to be a link?

Comment: yes, that's what I'm trying to do. To unlink "unlinkThis" so it is just text.

Comment: I've failed to find a way for you to do that. But I have an idea: to split your goal into 3 subgoals. 1) find start of the current word([is not easy at all](https://github.com/ianstormtaylor/slate/issues/4162)) and move selection there; 2) use `Transforms.splitNodes` to split at that point 3) move to newly created element and convert link to text with `Transforms.unwrapNodes`.

Comment: wondering, if traversing through raw value with those arrays and `childrend` objects to transform might be easier